# PHP array to Javascript in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops

First of all I have the following MySQL table name as **store_items** :

```
id ref store item qty sell
1  2   m1    001  1   12.00
2  2   m1    002  3   12.00
3  3   m3    004  4   5.00
4  3   m3    003  8   10.00
```

And starting with a simple PHP code to convert the above rows to an array

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM store_items ORDER by store Asc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

//This is for moving PHP array to JS array ? Not sure if it is correct
$js_arr = json_encode($data);

?>
```

Now I have been looking for a way rather than displaying it as a table , so I want to place those results inside an Excel look alike, so I found this plugin called : **Javascript Handsontable**

Moving on , after placing the style sheets and the scripts :

```
<script src="http://localhost/handsontable-master/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/handsontable-master/dist/handsontable.full.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/handsontable-master/demo/css/samples.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/handsontable-master/demo/css/samples.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/handsontable-master/demo/css/samples.css">

<style type="text/css">
body {background: white; margin:  auto;}
h2 {margin: 20px 0;}
</style>


<div id="example" class="handsontable htColumnHeaders"></div>
```

So the Problem arises over here :

```
<script>
var array_code = '<?php echo $js_arr; ?>';
//Alerting result to make sure its correct
alert(array_code);

$(document).ready(function () {

//Not sure how to display the results here ???
  var
    data = 
    [
     array_code
    ],

    container = document.getElementById('example'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });


  function bindDumpButton() {

      Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {

        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
          var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
          var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
          var hot = window[instance];
          console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
        }
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();

});
```

But I can't achieve the correct display; what I'm aiming for is something like this:

[image: Correct result]

But the above picture is shown correct when `var data` array values are like this

```
var
    data = [
      ['1', '2', 'm1', '001', '1', '12.00'],
      ['2', '2', 'm1', '002', '3', '12.00'],
      ['3', '3', 'm3', '004', '4', '5.00'],

    ],
```

How can I place the PHP array values inside JS array correctly?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: $js_arr = json_encode($data) would produce JSON formatted data.

Comment: @Perumal93 sorry am i missing something here, is it correct or not ?

Comment: You want to take the array of data straight into the table and display them?

Comment: Yes exactly, I've tried my best but what i have achieved right now is that the whole array[0] values are placed in one cell A, not every value in it inside each cell like picture above.

Comment: If so, you're making it complicated then. I'll explain them in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something (in which case comment and i'll edit my answer), but I think you just need to replace:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

and your "data" should be exactly array_code

Comment: Let me try that, just a sec.

Comment: After replacing assoc to row, the alert box displays the results correctly but when showing it inside the table , it put every single character/num in a cell. If you want i will post picture of the result

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$js_arr = json_encode($data);` for displaying the data in the HTML table since it would produce JSON formatted data and if you're not going to manipulate the table using JavaScript, you can avoid doing this way. Just add the following HTML code and style it however you want:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if(!empty($data)): ?>
           <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
               <tr>
                  <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['ref'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['store'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['item'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['qty'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $row['sell'] ?></td>
               </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```